# ag-grid upgrade to v23.x : issue with typing files

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have been using ag-grid 6x version for a while for an angularJS app. Now, I'm trying to upgrade ag-grid to latest version 23.x . I used bower to install new the version and I'm trying to use the definition files but few 'd.ts' files are not compiling.  I need some help to successfully finish this upgrade.

Here is the error:

```
 bower_components/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/filter/provided/providedFilter.d.ts(50,5): error TS2416: Property 'setModel' in type 'ProvidedFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IFilterComp'.
      Type '(model: ProvidedFilterModel) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(model: any) => void | Promise<void>'.
        Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void>'.
          Type 'Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<void>': listOfWaiters, firstOneOnly, map
    bower_components/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/filter/provided/simpleFilter.d.ts(83,15): error TS2416: Property 'setModelIntoUi' in type 'SimpleFilter<M>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ProvidedFilter'.
      Type '(model: ISimpleFilterModel | ICombinedSimpleModel<M>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(model: ProvidedFilterModel) => Promise<void>'.
        Property 'waiters' is missing in type 'ag.grid.Promise<void>' but required in type 'import("D:/svn/Trunk/MAP/WebDev/bower_components/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/utils/promise").Promise<void>'.
    bower_components/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/filter/provided/simpleFilter.d.ts(91,15): error TS2416: Property 'resetUiToDefaults' in type 'SimpleFilter<M>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ProvidedFilter'.
      Type '(silent?: boolean) => ag.grid.Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(silent?: boolean) => import("D:/svn/Trunk/MAP/WebDev/bower_components/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/utils/promise").Promise<void>'.
        Type 'ag.grid.Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/svn/Trunk/MAP/WebDev/bower_components/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/utils/promise").Promise<void>'.
    bower_components/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/headerRendering/headerRootComp.d.ts(34,28): error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.
```

Typescript version: 3.9.2
ag-grid-community: 23.2.1
Angular 1.5.6 (i think angular version is not the problem here)